# How to change focus to notification pop-up in VS Code using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

The question is simple, I usually use my keyboard to navigate in VS Code, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, etc. but I haven't found a way to add a shorcut to toggle focus on the notification pop-up shown in the example.

Is there a way to do this?

Screenshot of notification pop-up in VS Code

[image]

I'm using VS Code 1.63.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I've found the `notifications.focusToasts` editor command, so I set up the following as a keyboard shortcut:

```
{
        "key": "ctrl+shift+=",
        "command": "notifications.focusToasts"
},
```

Comment: That's excellent! I'm wondering though: How do I _find_ a command like this?

Comment: @halloleo these are the [built-in commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands) that come with VS code, but I haven't found an official documentation containing all of them. You can get them from the extension API with `vscode.commands.getCommands()', anyway [here's a non-authoritative list](https://gist.github.com/skfarhat/4e88ef386c93b9dceb98121d9457edbf) someone else compiled containing all of them.

Comment: Thanks for getting back yo me! Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

There is an in-built keyboard shortcut in VS code that allows you to shift
[focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgtbE.png) on to the toast notifications without having to configure the .json file.

If you press the combination when one or more notifications pop up, focus will be shifted on to the top most one from where you can use `Tab` to navigate between options. If there are no notifications showing up, You will see the [notification center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzVHi.png) pop up when you press the combination.

Found this when I looked up for settings related to "notifications" in the Command Palette. [(As in this screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGqMx.png)

**Note** : Press the combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>  (hold `Ctrl` and Press `K`) leave `K`, then press the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> (hold `Shift` while holding `Ctrl` and press `N`.)

Answer (score 0):

According to this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/43770), these keybindings exist:

[image: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/43770]